# Optimize MYSQL query having lots of data

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization

Is there a better way to write this query as it is searching in around 400k rows and taking 50 seconds to get executed?

```
SELECT pfile_print_media_id
     , market.market_name
     , full_name
     , image
     , pfile_date
  FROM pfile_print_media
  LEFT 
  JOIN pfiles 
    ON pfiles.pfile_id = pfile_print_media.pfile_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN publications 
    ON publications.publication_id = pfile_print_media.publication_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN clients 
    ON pfiles.client_id = clients.client_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN client_markets 
    ON client_markets.client_id = clients.client_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN market 
    ON market.market_id = clients.market
 WHERE pfiles.media_type =  'PRINT'
   AND clients.market = 17
    OR client_markets.market_id = 17
    OR client_type = 'INTERNATIONAL'
 GROUP 
    BY pfiles.pfile_id
 ORDER 
    BY pfiles.pfile_date DESC
 LIMIT 4
```

Explain query output:

[image]

Comment: Table & index structure & number of rows in the tables is quite essential for any answer.

Comment: @JamesZ kindly see the image. Can we further optimize

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. This is what's known locally as a bad start.

Comment: @UdayB. You still need to provide the table and index structure for us to help effectively. Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pfile_print_media` to your question. Do the same for all the other tables as well.

Comment: Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` unless you have a real reason for `LEFT`.  Qualify each column so we can tell which table each is in.  The `GROUP BY` is ill-formed since you have things like the date that are not included in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

If no columns are used from publications table - may be replacing join with sub query to just check the existence of key will speed up the query.

Comment: Or get rid of that table if you don't care.